# Cycle through a set of numbers in clockwise direction

Tags: javascript, math

i have a number lying between 65 & 90

I want to shift a number to 13 places behind but the number should start  from 90 the moment it reduces to below 65.

e.g: if I have 67, it should become 79 but 78 should fall to 65 and 77 should fall to 90

I have tried using if loops

```
var n = 67

if ((n - 13) < 65) {
  console.log(90 - (13 - (n - 65)))
}
else {
  console.log(n - 13)
}
```

But how can I use arithmetic to simplify my code?

Comment: 67 should go to 79, if I am right?

Comment: Then my calculation is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the base value of zero by subtracting the offset of `65`, add the shift value and use the reaminder to get the value inside of the interval of zero to 25, then add the offset again.

> It looks like [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) with [ROT13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13):
>
> ```
> from 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90
>      >A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y  Z
>       N  O  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y  Z >A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M
>  to  78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77
> ```

```js
function shiftBy(value, shift) {
    return (value - 65 + shift) % 26 + 65;
}

console.log(shiftBy(67, 13)); // 80
console.log(shiftBy(77, 13)); // 90
console.log(shiftBy(78, 13)); // 65
```